# Delete commits on remote git

Tags: git, github, git-reset

I have a `dev` branch on which we push everything. The last commit breaks our entire build and I need to remove the same. For local i used

`git reset --hard <SHA_ID>`

Which works well for local repo but when I try to push the changes are rejected because the tip of current branch is behind remote and shows me to use `git pull` before pushing it again.

My question is, how do I make the remote go to the same HEAD as my local repo and delete the last commit.

Comment: Force push? Or push a commit explicitly rolling the change back, rather than trying to revert.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `--force` argument to "reset" a remote branch to the same commit on your local repo:

```
$ git push origin --force
```

Note that this is considered a bad practice, though, as you may cause quite a mess for people relying on this branch. A friendlier approach would be to acknowledge the mistaken commit and fix it by `git revert`ing it, instead of trying to "act as though it never happened" with `git reset`.

Comment: Can't accept before 10 mins will do it then. Thanks for the help :) Also one confirmation `git reset` is only there for files that are not commited right?We already made a commit and pushed the stuff to remote

Comment: @georoot I don't understand your followup question. If you use `git reset <some old commit>` you will effectively lose all your commits after it.

Comment: sorry my bad i though you wrote `git reset .` just noticed `.` not a part of command :)